# Blender 2.80 crashes when starting up in Win 10

Tags: system

Blender 2.80 crashes on start on my new MSI. Have tried to install and run 2.79 as well -- same thing. I need help badly and appreciate every response.

The pattern is as follows 
 1. click and execute icon
 2. blank screen
 3. dos-prompt an text written very swift (hard to detect, but something with "Failed to set ... Get ... instead" )
 4. Return to Win OS

The pc specification is as attached. I wonder why the Intel displaycard appears under System Settings

With kind and hopeful regards
Mikael

[image]

**U P D A T E # 0 1 --- running "blender_debug_log.cmd", result:**

```
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
Blender 2.80 (sub 75)
Build: 2019-07-29 09:44 AM Windows 
argv[0] = blender
argv[1] = --debug
argv[2] = --python-expr
argv[3] = import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.sysinfo(filepath=r'C:\Users\epost\AppData\Local\Temp\blender\debug_logs\blender_system_info.txt')
read file 
  Version 280 sub 39 date unknown hash unknown
AL lib: (EE) SetChannelMap: Failed to match front-center channel (2) in channel map
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF9C9B99BCA
Module  : C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvmi.inf_amd64_be601cb137b2b59d\nvwgf2umx.dll
```

Dont know if nessesary but I couldn't find the file `blender_system_info.text` mentioned here:

[image]

**U P D A T E  # 0 2 --- --- updating NVIDIA driver, result:**

Succes!

[image]

Comment: Two things to check: 1) Please run dxdiag and check the display tab. Is the GeForce GTX 1060 listed? 2) Start Blender in debug mode to capture the output that (potentially) comes after the AL lib message. Open the install directory of Blender and run `blender_debug_log.cmd`. Add the output from the debug log to your question formatted as code (using the `{}` button).

Comment: Many thanks for your response! :-) 
I got the first part, running dxdiag and tried to run Blender in (I presume) debug mode grabbing the resulting prompt. But must confess I'm not so familiar with Windows system acronyms, so perhaps I've messed something up. 

And perhaps may I have confused Developer Mode with Safe Mode(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode)?. Yet I couldn't run "blender_debug_log.cmd". Please check out screen dumps to see ...

https://ibb.co/syBPSs7
https://ibb.co/0fqh3bF 
https://ibb.co/xg5Q698 

Kind regards -- Mikael

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, `blender_debug_log.cmd` starts Blender in debug mode. You can simply double-click the file. It's in Blender's install directory.

Comment: Sorry for my clumsyness and thanks for your patience:-) Updating my thread I've submitted the output above ...

Comment: Your graphics driver is out-dated and seems to cause the crash. Install the most recent one and check if that solves the problem (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx).

Comment: It worked! Thanks alot for your kind help! I'm so relieved :-)
Kind regards from Mikael and Copenhagen where the sun shines.